# Codeigniter - can't update database when using variable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have very strange problem...It looks like i can't update database ( from textarea field ) when i'm using variable inside query.
Sample from model:

This works:

```
public function update_vendor_about ( $id, $txt )
{
    $data = array ( "vendor_about" => $txt, );        
    $this->db->where("id", $id);        
    $this->db->update("users", $data); 
}
```

but, this does not work:

```
public function update_vendor_about ( $id, $txt )
{
    $data = array ( "vendor_about" => 'sometext', );        
    $this->db->where("id", $id);        
    $this->db->update("users", $data); 
}
```

Call from controller:

```
$message = $this->input->post('profile_about');
$this->user_model->update_vendor_about ( $active_user_id, $message );
```

Model gets `$txt` OK, i can see it and output it properly.
Same thing happens if i write entire `UPDATE` query manually.

I think problem could be in actual `$txt` content, so i tried with `trim()`, `stripslashes()`, replacing `\n\r`, etc, but nothing helps...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you `echo` this query and post the result here?

Comment: can you var_dump($txt) and give output?

Comment: @AnkiiGangrade that looks OK: "UPDATE `users` SET `vendor_about` = 'sometext' WHERE `id` = '20' "

Comment: @KunalPradhan var_dump also looks ok: "array(1) { ["vendor_about"]=> string(4) "sometext" }"

Comment: did you pass it in model function example function `edit_user($txt) {}`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yes, i can see value of that variable from the model.

Comment: Please edit main post and add controller where you load that function and the full model function

Comment: @zbrka : Copy the query and run in phpmyadmin. Will this work?

Comment: Is the variable $active_user_id a uri segement example `$active_user_id = $this->uri->segment(3)` example `http://localhost/project/user/edit/2`

Answer (score 0):

Your $txt is key => value array. Specify key when you are accessing array.

```
$data = array ( "vendor_about" => $txt["vendor_about"] );        
$this->db->where("id", $id);        
$this->db->update("users", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you missed array index in update query :

```
$data = array ("vendor_about"=>$txt['vendor_about']);        
$this->db->where("id",$id);        
$this->db->update("users",$data);
```

Comment: Hmm, no i get "Illegal string offset" error this way....Also, i have noticed that sometimes ( absolutely random ) my code actually works...Could this be issue with the database itself?

Comment: Can you `print_r($txt);` in model and paste here?

Comment: Ok, it's definitly something with getting data from textarea, if i use something like $this->user_model->update_vendor_about ( $active_user_id, "my text" ); - it works ok.

Comment: Can you paste `print_r($txt);` result here?

Answer (score 0):

use echo $this->db->last_query(); you will get query and then run it in phpmyadmin or sqlyog and you will get error message and then you can resolve it.

Comment: That works, row is updated like it should, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this issue is server related.
I have just tried it on another server with Apache 2.4.9, PHP 5.5.12 and MySQL 5.6.17 - and it works.